# Creating a dockerfile with python and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my project, I have a flask application which connects to a postgresql DB, and I need to package it into a docker. I created the Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD . /todo
WORKDIR /todo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and the docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python run.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/todo
  links:
    - db

db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: todo
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: todo321
    POSTGRES_DB: todo
  ports:
      - 5432:5432
  restart: always
```

I have the configuration file, specifying the DB connection for the flask app.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://todo:todo321@db/todo"
```

then ran the `docker-compose build` without any error. But when try to run the container with the table creation with the migration script:

```
docker-compose run web python migrate.py db migrate
```

It gives me erorrs:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

dependencies:

```
flask == 1.0.3
flask-restful == 0.3.7
flask-sqlalchemy == 2.4.0
marshmallow == 2.19.2
flask-marshmallow == 0.10.1
flask-script == 2.0.6
flask-migrate == 2.5.2
psycopg2 == 2.8.2
passlib == 1.7.1
flask-jwt-extended == 3.18.2
marshmallow-sqlalchemy
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: You have to use the docker database service name, here "db", instead of "localhost" for connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `up` to start your containers first, and then execute migrations:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose run web python migrate.py db migrate
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. What is the cause of this error? is the postgresql db is not up and running or the python application cannot connect to the postgresql and run the db scripts? or do I need to add a script to explicitly create the database?

Comment: Postgres isn't on localhost, it's at the host db

Comment: @Jeremy, how do I find the ip? in my flask application I have the configuration file, which has the DB uri: SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://todo:todo321@localhost/todo". So it's only this part needs to be changed (localhost), or should I add the host information to the docker-compose.yml file as well?

Comment: @Jeremy, I changed the DB URI as SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://todo:todo321@db/todo", and ran the build command and then docker-compose run web python migrate.py db migrate &&  python migrate.py  db upgrade. I'm no longer getting the operation error. But I'm getting a new error saying,   File "migrate.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_script import Manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script'. I've posted the requirement.txt file above, which installs the flask_script. Could you please help me with this?